# how to clear a asp dropdown list and populate using ajax?

Tags: ajax, vb.net, jquery, drop-down-menu

What i am trying to do is get a user to change one drop down, which then calls an ajax function which posts to the code behind (vb.net file) then clears and populates another asp dropdown list with the data returned from the function..hope i made sense

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.manuf').change(function () {
             $.ajax({
                      type: "POST", 
                      url: "ajax.aspx/GetModel",
                      data: '{' +
                            'ManufID:"' + $('.manuf').val() + '"' +
                           '}',
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function(msg) {
                         var data = json_parse(msg.d);
                         if (data.error) {
                              alert("Error!");
                              return;
                         }

                          alert(data.model);
                      },
                      error: function(msg) {
                          alert('Get Details Failure: ' + msg);
                      }
                  });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Check this link http://forums.asp.net/t/1202895.aspx/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad - you can write your ajax call like this -

```
$.ajax({ url :"/website/myurl", type:"POST", contentType:"application/json;", dataType:"json", data : "{ 'id' : '" + $("select[id*=selCurrentManuf]").val() + "' } ",
        success : function (return_data) {
             var data = $.parseJSON(return_data);
             // code to add the contents of data to other list
             $("select[id*=selCurrentModel]").empty().append($("<option>").attr("value","0").text("Choose..."));
             // for the dropdown list clear all options and add a 'choose...' as the first option

            $.each(data, function (i, d) { $("<option>").attr("value", d.k).text(d.v).appendTo($("select[id*=selCurrentModel]")); });

}, error:function () {
             // handle error
            }     
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you know how to fetch data from the backend via ajax. Something like this -

```
$.ajax({ url :"/website/myurl", type:"POST", dataType:"application/json"; data:"json", 
    success : function (return_data) {
          var data = $.parseJSON(return_data);
          // code to add the contents of data to other list

        }, error:function () {
         // handle error
        }     
});
```

Lets say you are getting it in a variable `data` which is an array.

You may try something like this -

```
 $("select[id*=selCurrentModel]").empty().append($("<option>").attr("value", "0").text("Choose..."));
 // for the dropdown list clear all options and add a 'choose...' as the first option

 $.each(data, function (i, d) { $("<option>").attr("value", d.k).text(d.v).appendTo($("#ddlExperience")); });
```

// user $.each to iterate the data object which

You may try things on these lines.... Hope this helps.

Comment: 1. to get the url use - Page.Resolve("default.aspx/somefunction")

Comment: 2. yes, i meant that only, but better use ID because you may be having several elements with that class name so, its not advisable practice.